# Rgrep in Emacs to use ripgrep

Tags: utf-8, emacs, grep, utf-16, ripgrep

How can we customize Emacs' rgrep to use ripgrep (rg executable) -- making it working for searching in Latin 1, UTF-8 and UTF-16 at the same time?

The idea is to reuse the standard rgrep command of Emacs, so that we can use next-error and previous-error as well...

I don't see how to fully integrate the  (for the base dir) and the  (for the files matched) specifiers, among others.

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template
                    "rg -uu -g <F> <R> <D>")
```

will produce (when searching within *.txt files)

```
rg -uu -g \( -iname \*.txt \) test .
error: Invalid value for '--max-count <NUM>': invalid digit found in string

Grep exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Aug  6 00:23:58
```

Comment: `rg` doesn't support `find` predicates. Just normal globbing. You have to combine it with the `find` command.

Comment: @JürgenHötzel Thanks for the info. Could you show how to write it then (and publish it as an answer)?

Comment: There are two packages in melpa that work with ripgrep: `rg` and `ripgrep`.  I'm trying out `rg` now, because it says it supports `wgrep-ag`; `wgrep` is one of my favorite features.

Answer (score 2):

`grep-find-template` is for using a `grep`command in combination with `find`. This works for me:

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template "find <D> <X> -type f <F> -exec rg <C> --no-heading -H  <R> /dev/null {} +")
```

If you want to use `rg` without `find` you have to use `lgrep` and customize:

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-template "rg --no-heading -H -uu -g <F> <R> <D>")
```

Comment: Thanks. To what should grep-command and grep-find-command be set, for rg?

Comment: Got a "Search failed. This means there is unmatched expression somewhere or we are at the beginning/end of file." when testing M-x rgrep. I don't understand the + sign at the end of your string. Is that right?

Comment: The `+` is part of `find` syntax. It defines the end of the `exec` action.

Comment: Your solution (dunno what happened the first time) or `(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template "find <D> <X> -type f <F> -exec rg <C> --no-heading -H  <R> /dev/null {} \\;")` almost work for me: message `/dev/null: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)` is displayed between the command and the results (in the `*grep*` buffer). And matches are not displayed in color anymore. Any idea what's wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: In fact, the message about `/dev/null` appears between results as well - it's part of them. For some reason...

Comment: I doubt that makes a diff, but I'm on Cygwin (Emacs and shell).

Comment: Removing the `/dev/null` from your string does remove the first line with the error message... Why was that needed?

Comment: With the above command, I get no color for the matched text -- while we do in a shell prompt. Is there something special to do to get it?